# What language to learn for microcontroller programming?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I'm getting into microcontroller programming and have been hearing contrasting views. What language is most used in the industry for microcontroller programming? Is this what you use in your own work? If not, why not?

P.S.: I'm hoping the answer is not assembly language.

Comment: Assemb... wait...

Comment: Well it's hard to say.. seeing that microcontrollers are relatively low level devices that typically have non-portable instruction sets. What family are you getting into?

Comment: I was trying to get into a family named Brady, but that was a while back. ;-)

Comment: unless you are designing a microcontroller rather than for a microcontroller I don't think you need verilog

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596929/embedded-platform-development-in-c for an interesting survey of non-C options.

Comment: I can't wait to learn assembly (it's so low level!) and we will be  learning to program microcontrollers at school soon! Yippi!

Answer (score 38):

In my experience, you absolutely must know C, and assembly language helps too.

Comment: Nice short direct answer to the question (not like mine!).

Comment: You should have a general understanding of how C is translated into assembler, and any relevant platform quirks - e.g. you can write pointer-to-structure code for the PIC, but it will suck. Being able to read assember will help in debugging it. You seldom need to write in assembler, C provides raw enough access.

Answer (score 13):

Unless you are dealing with very bare-bones microcontrollers (like the RS08 series), C is by far the language of choice. Get to know C, understand functionality like volatile and const. Also understand the architecture - what is efficient, what isn't, what can the CPU do. These will differ wildly from a "desktop" environment. Learn to love stdint.h.

You will encounter C++ (or a restricted subset) as projects scale up.

However, you need to understand the CPU and how to read basic assembly as a debugging tool. You can't become an excellent embedded developer without this skillset.

Comment: stdint.h is good. Especially for testing your code on a PC.

Answer (score 13):

What 'contrasting' views have you heard?  To some extent it will depend on the microcontroller and the application.  However C is available for almost all architectures (I hesitate to say *all*, but probably all that you will ever encounter); so on that point alone, learning C would give you the greatest coverage.

For all architectures, the availability of an assembler and a C compiler are pretty much a given.  For 32-bit and most 16-bit architectures C++ will also be available. Notable exceptions I have encountered are Microchip's PIC24/dsPIC parts for which C++ is not supported by Microchip's own GNU based compiler (although 3rd party compilers may do so).

While there are C++ compilers for 8 bit microcontroller's C++ is not ubiquitous on such platforms, and often the compilers are subsets of the full language.  For the types (or more specifically the size) of application for which 8-bit is usually employed, C++ may be useful but not to the extent that it is on much larger applications, so C is generally adequate.

There are lot of [myths about C++ in embedded systems](http://www.embedded.com/98/9802fe3.htm); while the language is larger than C and has constructs that may compromise the performance or capacity of your system, you only pay for what you use with C++.  But of course if what you use is just the C subset, the C would be adequate in any case.

The point about C (and C++) is that it is a systems level language; it will run on your microprocessor with no additional support save a very simple runtime start-up to initialise the processor (and possibly external SDRAM), initialise static data, establish a stack, and in the case of C++ invoke static constructors.  This is why along with target specific assembler, it is used to build operating systems and kernels - it needs no operating system or kernel itself to run.

One of the reasons I suggested that it may depend on the microcontroller is that if for example it is an ARM9 with a few Mb of external SDRAM, and at least say 4Mb Flash (also usually external - memory takes up a lot of die space), then you could run a 'heavyweight' OS on it such as Linux, WinCE, or Symbian, or even a large RTOS such as QNX or VxWorks.  Then your choice of language (once you got the OS working), would be influenced by the OS, though for real-time applications C and C++ would still dominate, (or often Ada in military, avionics, and some transport applications).

For mid-size applications - a few hundred KBytes of code and data space - C# running on the .NET-Micro platform is possible; However I sat in a presentation of this at the Embedded Systems Show in the UK a few years ago, just after it was when it was launched; when I asked the question "but is it real-time", and was told, "no you need WinCE for that", there was a gasp and a groan from much of the audience, and some stopped wasting their time an left the presentation there and then (including me).

So I am still interested in the 'contrasting' opinions you have heard; because although it is *possible* to use other languages; the answer to your question:

> What language is most used in the
>   industry for microcontoller
>   programming?

then the definitive answer is C; for the reasons I have given. For anyone who might choose to contest this assertion [here are the statistics](http://www.embedded.com/design/218600142?_requestid=360793) (note the different survey method after 2004 explained in the text).  However just to add to the collection of alternatives, I once spent two years programming in [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) on embedded systems, and I know of people still using it, but it is a bit of a niche.

Answer (score 11):

I've successfully used both C and C++ but in almost any microcontroller project you will need to be familiar with the assembly language of the target micro. If only for debugging low level hardware issues assembly will be indispensable, even if it is a cursory familiarity.

I think the hardest thing for me when moving from a desktop environment to a micro was that almost everything needs to be allocated statically. You won't often use malloc/new in a micro unless maybe it has external RAM.

I notice that you also tagged your question with FPGA and Verilog, take a look at [Altium](http://www.altium.com), they have a C to Hardware compiler that works really well with their integrated environment.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding assembler:

- Prefer C/C++ over assembler as much as possible. You'll get better productivity by writing as much as possible in C or C++. That includes being able to run some of your code on a PC, which can help developing the higher-level code (application-layer functions).
- On many embedded platforms, it's good to have someone on the project who is comfortable with a little assembler. Mostly to get start-up code and interrupts going nicely, and perhaps functions for interrupt enable/disable. That's not the same as knowing it really thoroughly--just a basic working knowledge will be sufficient.
- If you're porting an [RTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) (e.g. [µC/OS-II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroC/OS-II)) to a new platform, then you'll have to know your assembler more. But hopefully your RTOS supports your platform well already.
- If you're pushing up against CPU performance limits, you probably need to know assembler more thoroughly. But hopefully you're not pushing performance limits much, because that can be a drag on a project's viability.
- If you're writing for a [DSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor), you probably need to know the DSP's assembler fairly thoroughly.

Comment: Before writing in assembly, write the function in C or C++.  Next have the compiler generate the assembly listing of that function.  The compiler has done most of the work for you; just twiddle as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Microcontrollers were originally programmed only in assembly language, but various high-level programming languages are now also in common use to target microcontrollers. These languages are either designed specially for the purpose, or versions of general purpose languages such as the C programming language. Compilers for general purpose languages will typically have some restrictions as well as enhancements to better support the unique characteristics of microcontrollers. Some microcontrollers have environments to aid developing certain types of applications. Microcontroller vendors often make tools freely available to make it easier to adopt their hardware.

Many microcontrollers are so quirky that they effectively require their own non-standard dialects of C, such as SDCC for the 8051, which prevent using standard tools (such as code libraries or static analysis tools) even for code unrelated to hardware features. Interpreters are often used to hide such low level quirks.

Interpreter firmware is also available for some microcontrollers. For example, BASIC on the early microcontrollers Intel 8052[4]; BASIC and FORTH on the Zilog Z8[5] as well as some modern devices. Typically these interpreters support interactive programming.

Simulators are available for some microcontrollers, such as in Microchip's MPLAB environment. These allow a developer to analyze what the behavior of the microcontroller and their program should be if they were using the actual part. A simulator will show the internal processor state and also that of the outputs, as well as allowing input signals to be generated. While on the one hand most simulators will be limited from being unable to simulate much other hardware in a system, they can exercise conditions that may otherwise be hard to reproduce at will in the physical implementation, and can be the quickest way to debug and analyze problems.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know assembly language programming.You need to have good knowledge in C  and also C++ too.so work hard on thse things to get better expertize on micro controller programming.

Comment: In 20 years as an embedded system developer I have not learned a complete assembler instruction set since the 8051.  You need to know what assembly language is, and may *sometimes* need to be able to read and understand the instruction set manual, but I would not over emphasise this requirement, unless you are having to write the C-runtime start-up code from scratch (and it is not often an existing example is not available).

Comment: Assembly is no longer a requirement for many microcontrollers. Many Bachelor of Engineering studies are even dropping the course for having a lack of future. C and C++ all the way.

Answer (score 2):

And don't forget about VHDL.

Comment: For microcontrollers, no so much.

Comment: He does have an fpga tag though

Answer (score 2):

For microcontrollers assembler comes before C.  Before the ARMs started pushing into this market the compilers were horrible and the memory and ROM really tiny. There are not enough resources or commonality to port your code so writing in C for portability makes no sense.

Some microcontroller's assembler is less than desirable, and ARM is taking over that market. For less money, less power, and less footprint you can have a 32-bit processor with more resources. It just makes sense.  Much if your code will still not port, but you can probably get by with C.

Bottom line, assembler and C.  If they advertise BASIC or Java or something like that, mark that company on your blacklist and move on.  Been there, done that, have the scars to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

First Assembly. After C.

I think that who knows Assembly and C are better than who knows only C.